# .Net Gen2 garbage collection doesn't reclaim Gen 2 heap completely

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

**Facts:**

1. My app is hosted in IIS8 (Windows Server 2012)
2. .Net version is 4.6.1, hence GC flavor used is *Background server*
3. Gen 2 heap size, 15 minutes after app is serving traffic, is **12gb** (very reasonable since our app holds a lot of data).
4. After six days serving traffic:

   - "Gen 2 heap size" counter is **17gb**
   - "# Gen 2 collections" counter is 3600 (which means there is full gc cycle once every 2.5 minutes, which is good for us)
   - Average Gen2 collection takes about **300ms**
   - Calling *GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced)* reduces Gen 2 heap size to **12gb** (invoked manually using a API)
   - Induced GC collection takes **~3seconds** (probably because it is *blocked* and not *background*).

Obviously, there is no memory leak in our application since inducing GC shrinks the heap size.

It seems that induced GC cycle is doing **more work** than regular GC cycle but couldn't find any information about this.

**The question is:**

Why doesn't a regular background Gen2 collection shrink Gen2 heap back to normal figures, while inducing GC does?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to answer questions about such giant heap sizes with so little info.  Recent framework versions have tweaks in the GC to accommodate it, but they don't tell exactly what they did.  Key is to avoid the worst-case scenario.  And key to that is avoid doing any work aggressively releasing address space.  Because you are likely to need it again later.  Recent questions about this suggest that this is what they do now.  Do avoid defeating it.